# Json ignore collections in entities

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I use `@JsonIgnore` to ignore some collections in my entity to be send in ajax as `json` element.

To generate the mapping classes I use `hibernate tools` .

My problem is that i change often my database schema so I loose my `@JsonIgnore` annotation when i generate entities again.

So is there a solution to add them automatically or add them in a separate file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [dynamically add annotations at runtime](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.ro/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html).

1. You need to add a Spring Bean with a @PostConstruct init method.
2. In the init method you dynamically add entities to the entities class properties you want to ignore.